# What is the Laurent series of $1/\sin^2(z)$ at $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to calculate the Laurent series of  $1/\sin^2(z)$ at $0$?

I have tried using the Taylor series for $\sin z$, but I don't get anywhere.  All I get is a denominator with an ugly series in it, and I don't see how to rearrange it.

Do I have to use the derivative and integral formulas for the coefficients of Laurent series or is there a smarter way?

Comment: An explicit formula for the Laurent series of $\csc z$ is easily searchable (it involves Bernoulli numbers); square it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the trick to use when you see a common analytic function in the denominator is to use the geometric series. In your case, you can rewrite the denominator as $\frac{1-\cos(2z)}{2}$. Then, $\cos(2z)$ can be made less than $1$ on some sufficiently small neighborhood of zero (not including zero) by continuity, so you can use the geometric series to argue that, on this neighborhood,

$$ \frac{1}{\sin^2z} = \frac{2}{1-\cos(2z)} = 2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos^n(2z) $$

Then, you just compute directly the terms you need.

This technique can also be used to find the Laurent series for $\cot z$. Test it out yourself, it's a neat exercise.

Comment: Ah so then the series is only valid for $|cos(2z)|<1$, i see. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You can linearise first: $\sin^2z=\dfrac{1-\cos 2z}2$, so
$$\frac1{\sin^2z}= \frac{2}{1-\cos 2z}=\frac{2}{2z^2-\cfrac{2z^4}{3}+\cfrac{4z^6}{45}-\dotsm}=\frac{1}{z^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\cfrac{z^2}{3}+\cfrac{2z^4}{45}-\dotsm},$$
then perform the division of $1$ by $1-\dfrac{z^2}{3}+\dfrac{2z^4}{45}-\dotsm\:$ along *increasing* powers of $z$.